# "KeyError: 'non-free-firmware'" after running apt-get update

Tags: bash, kali-linux, python3

Running an update with the following command :

`apt-get update`

returns :

```
Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 27, in <module>
    col.create(db)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 95, in create
    self._fill_commands(con)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 143, in _fill_commands
    self._parse_single_contents_file(con, f, fp.stdout)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 282, in _parse_single_contents_file
    priority = component_priorities[component]
KeyError: 'non-free-firmware'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
```

Could someone please explain the traceback ?

Comment: Most likely it means you shouldn't be using kali linux, is my guess.  Kali is meant for expert users, and is not intended to be used like ubuntu or debian in terms of upgrading, adding repos, etc. You didn't give a single detail about when or how this error generated, that is, what did you do before this? Add a repo?

Comment: Firstly, I've been using kali for a couple years, this is a new issue thats arisen since moving to windows.. and who said im using it like ubuntu anyway ? You can clearly se it says "apt-get update" at the top of the screen, which is obviously how it generated, as you can see...

Comment: "_I've been using kali for a couple year_" vs. comment from your [closed Ask Ubuntu posting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455126/does-anyone-know-whats-up-with-this-problem-executing-scripts-aptupdatepost) _"I don't now what to do and kali is debian based, supposedly similar to ubuntu."_ ... I have my doubts. Kali is not the slightest "similar to Ubuntu". [Kali is ... specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT ... a general-purpose Linux.](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)

Comment: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: yeah whats your point ? just because it's not meant for the same thing doesn't mean very much in regards to my question, its made in a very similar way. If you don't know the answer just say so, don't get touched Big man, claiming to be a Lizszsard XD

Comment: _"made in a very similar way"_ - Up to a point. Just like [ThrustSSC](https://images.saymedia-content.com/.image/t_share/MTc0OTYxNTk5NDQwOTU1MjM4/thrust-ssc-more-than-1000-kmph-car.jpg) is up to a point "made in a very similar way" as any car.

Comment: yeh I got it, was a software issue.

Comment: What’s the point of piling on just because the OP is using Kali? I don’t think it’s fair to expect all Kali users to be *distro* experts and know every last detail of changes happening to the distribution. How many of the commenters and downvoters knew what the problem was? Probably none...

Answer (score 2):

Kali has a new section, `non-free-firmware`, but the version of `command-not-found` you have doesn’t know about it (it was [added in version 23.04.0](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1411346/accepted-command-not-found-23040-1-source-into-unstable/)).

To fix this, disable the hook:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50command-not-found{,.disabled}
```

You will then be able to run `apt update` as usual. Once you have a fixed version of `command-not-found`, re-enable the hook:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50command-not-found{.disabled,}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go nano in /etc/apt/sources.list and add 'deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main contrib non-free' after 'deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free'. Comment both lines, save it and try to update again. Good luck.